# select asp.net grid view row on jquery dialog box and populate on text fields on parent form

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, gridview

I have an asp.net page that contains gridview. It has one or more record. If a user choose a row, it will close jquery dialog modal and populate parent form

I have attached the sample. It does not look nice, but it is easier for me to create in word than try to prototype on ASP.NET

[image: mockup for the gridview]

Once user click the button (pick this one), let's say first one, id (1) and name (a) will be populated on the parent page

I have researched many websites. Most websites have helpful hints if there is a static button. When a user click the button, something happen. However, the griview is constructed dynamically, so are the buttons. Obvious, binding the button on jquery dialog box model will not work.

What is the best approach to handle this

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Why wont Jquery work? I'm sure the buttons have an id or name..

```
`$('#tableID tbody').on("click", "tr td:nth-child(1) a", function () {
var $row = $(this).closest("tr");
var ID = $row.find('$row td:nth-child(2) label').val();
$.get("/Home/MyModal/" +ID, function (data) {
    $("#modalDiv").html(data);
    $("#modal").modal('show');
   });
});`
```

In the example I make a call to the mvc controller which returns a partial view loaded with the modal data. That html data returned from the controller is then passed to a div with an ID of 'modalDiv'. Then I open the modal using modal.show event.

Not sure if this is what you were looking for but this will load a modal with the information

Comment: My problem is I don't know the button ID. As I mentioned, the gridview is constructed dynamically. There could be 0, 1, or more rows. Therefore assigning the ID ahead of the time. I did bind the javascript function in rowcommand function. Most of examples I have seen, people assign the data in jquery dialog initialization. That is not going to work because I need the button id.

Comment: using jquery you can get the buttons without even knowing the ID....search by class : $('.classname')...search for a link inside a gridview $('#gridViewName > a')...you have many options to select this element without knowing the ID

Comment: you can also use IE or Chrome developer options to see the classes on those elements

Comment: can you show me an example. That is what I am stuck. I can user .classname as selector, but I have to bind it correctly. when the button is clicked, i have to populate the data correctly from the corresponding row.

Comment: Your ID element in the table is that a label?

Comment: In the new answer I assumed the ID was a label element inside the tables td element

Comment: Like I said, there could be multiple rows, getting the id is little bit tricky. I was hoping can tell me how I can get the id dynamically. If that is not doable, any other trick I can choose

Comment: I used MVC about 2 years ago. At that time, we did not know can use all the nice feature like ASP.net  (like databind). I remember I had to write a loop to create the row dynamically. I remember I even created the id dynamically (such as id1, id2, id3, etc). Think about it, I can track down the id during the click, but how do i implement id(x) click. I like to know the answer. I do miss MVC

Answer (score 0):

I did a lot research. I ended using postmessage method.

http://benalman.com/code/projects/jquery-postmessage/examples/iframe/

I really don't like this solution. I am doing research on security risk related to postmessage. if anyone has better, let me know.

Here is the algorithm
1) Once the user clicks one of the links/buttons (remember they can be multiple rows), save the current row information in the hidden fields
2) call javascript to postmessage (see the link)
3) in the parent listen to the event (see the link)
4) assign the hidden fields to the various text fields on the parent form
5) oh reference the fields in iframe is little bit tricky. Luckily, someone on the internet shows me this trick
http://codedisplay.com/jquery-to-get-set-read-access-iframe-content-textbox-value-data-using-asp-net-c-vb-net/

6) close jquery dialog box

My original plan was creating some kind of events on dialog box during the creation to do all the work. I am hoping people here can help me that.

At least i figure out the solution. I just need to address the security issue.